# Showing this distribution is uniform

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X\sim Unif(B(0,\sqrt{n})$, a uniform random vector in the closed n-ball. I am trying to use the following expression for $X$ in a proof:

$$X=\sqrt{n}\frac{g}{\|g\|_2}r^{\frac{1}{n}}\,,$$
where $g\sim N(0,\mathbb{1}_n)$ and $r\sim Unif([0,1])$.

However, in order to show this expression is a valid representation of $X$, I of course need to show it is uniform. I understand that I am supposed to show the probability of any event is equal to the volume of the subset of $B(0,\sqrt{n})$ divided by the volume of $B(0,\sqrt{n})$. Is there some other way of showing this?

EDIT:

$B(a,b):=$ the closed n-ball centred at $a$, with radius $b$.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I have corrected it accordingly, apologies. But in this case $B(a,b)$ means the closed ball centred at $a$, with radius $b$.

Comment: @kimchilover Will do!

Comment: Intuitively, your representation is correct up to possibly a nonlinear deformation of $R$, so all you need check is that you have got the correct distribution of $\|X\|$ this way, which boils down to calculating  $\mu(B(0,t))/\mu(B(0,1))$ and  $P(R^{1/n}\le t)$.